# Spark Cassandra Connector 3.0.0 - How to enable DirectJoin - Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, join, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have cassandra 3.11.9, spark 3.0.1 and spark-cassandra-connector 3.0.0(dependency). I am trying to use the Direct Join of the SCC 3.0.0 but it seems that when I use join on below dataset I get the broadcast hash join of spark.

```
Dataset<Row> metlistinitial = sp.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
            .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                {
                    put("keyspace", "mdb");
                    put("table", "experiment");
                }
            })
            .load().select(col("experimentid"), col("description"))
            .join(dfexplist,"experimentid")
            .filter(col("description").notEqual("Unidentified"));
metlistinitial.explain();

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [experimentid#6, description#7]
+- *(1) BroadcastHashJoin [experimentid#6], [experimentid#4], Inner, BuildRight
   :- *(1) Project [experimentid#6, description#7]
   :  +- *(1) Filter NOT (description#7 = Unidentified)
   :     +- BatchScan[experimentid#6, description#7] Cassandra Scan: mdb.experiment
 - Cassandra Filters: []
 - Requested Columns: [experimentid,description]
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true])), [id=#19]
  +- LocalTableScan [experimentid#4]
```

Is there something I should to enable the direct join with a cassandra table? Right now it takes around 8 minutes to do the join and I want to see if it will be faster with the direct join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found it! It seems I just had to activate the Connector by adding

```
.config("spark.sql.extensions","com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions")
```

in the spark configuration. Amazing performance. Now it only takes 8 seconds!

Comment: you can find more information about joins in this blog post: https://alexott.blogspot.com/2020/07/spark-effective-joins-with-cassandra.html

Comment: Yup, it also helped me! Something that I just noticed though, Having a DirectJoin works really well and really fast if we want to fetch some records based on the partition key. But if we want to fetch 2billion records and directjoin them with a list of partition keys(i.e. 4.800 unique partition keys) it takes around 15-20minutes, while with BroadcastHashJoin of spark takes around 7minutes.

Comment: there are different things that you can tune, like, ratio when direct join stops working, etc. Also, if partition keys are given as `IN list`, then it may not automatically convert into direct join

Comment: This is very good news! No, I am not using filter.isin(list), just join. However I would like some more information on the directJoinSizeRatio. The formula is basically (table size * directJoinSizeRatio) > size of keys. By saying table size does it mean in bytes or number of rows? Also for size of keys, is it in bytes? Is there any formula to calculate cassandra table size in bytes or the size of keys? Also, does it mean the compacted space of cassandra? For example when I cfstats on a node it says 8.7716Gb.

Comment: Actually I just added it as a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66133389/spark-cassandra-connector-3-0-0-how-to-calculate-directjoinsizeratio