# spark-cassandra-connector 3.0.0 - How to calculate directJoinSizeRatio

Tags: join, cassandra, key, partition, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a 16 node cassandra cluster and a table which according to cfstats, in total is around (8.9 x 16 = )143Gb. I have a replication factor 3(I am not sure if it is relevant) and the number of the unique partition keys is 4.827. I am trying to calculate the ratio so to turn it off every time I want to join on more than 3.170 partition keys.

The formula of the directJoinSizeRatio parameter is:

```
(table size * directJoinSizeRatio) > size of keys
```

But, to what exactly the table size refers to. Is it the sum of the compacted sizes of the tables that cfstats says in every node? Is it just the size of the table in one node?

So, in my case I have 4827 uuids as strings. Would it be:

```
143.000.000.000 bytes * parameter > 3170 *36 bytes?
```

or

```
8.900.000.000 bytes * parameter > 3170 *36 bytes?
```

Does this mean that I really have to lower the parameter to i.e. 0,000000798 or 0,000012822 respectively?

**EDIT 1**

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE experiment(
experimentid varchar,
description text,
rt float,
intensity float,
mz float,
identifier text,
chemical_formula text,
filename text,
PRIMARY KEY ((experimentid),description, rt, intensity, mz, identifier, chemical_formula, filename)
```

);

P.S.: the table has around 2.2billion records

**EDIT 2**

I always join on the partition key and that is why it is fast I guess, i.e.:

```
Dataset<Row> metlistinitial2 = sp.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                    {
                        put("keyspace", "mdb");
                        put("table", "experiment");
                    }
                })
                .load().select(col("experimentid"), col("description"), col("intensity")).join(dfexplist,"experimentid").repartition(col("experimentid"));
```

and then there can be some groupby or more joins.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're operating on partition keys, then you may need to use them to calculate the desired ratio - in this case it should be: 3170/4827 ~= 0.657, but it won't be precise because your partitions could be smaller or bigger, so size estimate won't be exact.   Also, the size estimate is just estimate, so it won't be precise.  I would try to play with that ratio in the range of 0.6-0.66...

Comment: Eventually I want 2600 keys so this 2600/4827 ~= 0,538 would make sense indeed! But it seems that with directJoinSizeRatio=0.000000000000008 I get around 2600 partition keys! I guess the table is quite big for those keys?

Comment: are you talking about partition keys, or primary keys?

Comment: Very interesting question! So, when it says "size of keys" in the above formula it means the primary keys!!!! Then it makes sense why I have so small ratio!  Because my whole record is the primary key! Updated the question with the structure of the table!

Comment: it's interesting table structure, usually such big primary keys may lead to the bigger partitions that could be slower if you join only on them.  Can you show the join condition?

Comment: Of course, I put it in EDIT 2. The reason for such big primary key is that anything less than these 8 fields of the table may not be unique.